# Simulation of the injected noise to oscillator in Virtuoso

Tags: noise, oscillator, cadence, noise-spectral-density, lna

I have a differential LNA that injects current to an oscillator. I want to see the thermal noise injected to the oscillator. This noise is composed of the noise of oscillator + noise of the LNA.
Now in Noise analysis in Cadence i have to specify the output node (port) and the input port.
The output node is the output of LNA. That's where it should be.
But what about the input port??
If i put it in the input of LNA, I'll only be able to see the output noise of LNA (but not the oscillator), am i right?
So how can the noise of oscillator be taken into account?
Should i draw the plot of oscillator input referred noise and LNA output recferred noise seperately and then add up the curves?
And input and output in an oscillator are the same here. actually differential current injected from the LNA is the input and differential voltage of the oscillator is the output of oscillator. So both the input and output for the oscillator are the same nodes.   so how can i plot the curve of noise injected to the oscillator versus frequency in Virtuoso noise analysis?
[image: lna+oscillator]

Comment: The noise analysis is only for linear circuits, that excludes oscillators. Use the PNoise simulation instead! Look in the manual and the Spectre RF tutorials for examples.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I need to find the noise current injected to oscillator not the phase noise